# Is $\{\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\ \text{converges}\}$ a tail event?

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\dots$ is a sequence of random variables on some probability space. The tail $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{T}$ is defined as the intersection of $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{T}:=\bigcap_n\mathcal{F}_n$, where $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},\dots)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_n,X_{n+1},\dots$.

I know that  $\{\sum_{k=1}^n X_n\ \text{converges}\}$ is a tail event. But is $\{\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\ \text{converges}\}$ a tail event?

Comment: Basically, if you can change values of any finite collection of the $X_k$ without changing whether the event occurs, it's a tail event. That's the idea behind the definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every fixed $m\in\mathbb N$ we have:

$$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\text{ converges}\iff\frac1n\sum_{k=m}^nX_k\text{ converges}$$

or equivalently
$$\{\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\text{ converges}\}=\{\frac1n\sum_{k=m}^nX_k\text{ converges}\}$$

while evidently  $\{\frac1n\sum_{k=m}^nX_k\text{ converges}\}\in\mathcal F_m$.

This allows the conclusion that this event is an element of $\mathcal T:=\bigcap_m\mathcal F_m$.